# Regex: Extract parts of url before and after last period

Tags: regex, url

I have a url (http://www.something.com/subdirectory/image.jpg) and I would like to split the url into two parts using regex:

1) Capture first part of url before the last period (http://www.something.com/subdirectory/image)

2) Capture the last part of url after the last period (jpg)

The file extension will not always be jpg.

I have come up with something so far but it is capturing the string before the first period instead of the last:

```
/([^.]*)\.(.*)/
```

EDIT: Here's what I'm trying to do.  Replace the current src by adding "_On" to the end of the image name.

```
$(this).attr("src").replace(/(.*)\.([^.]+)$/, "$1_On.$2")
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help,
B

Comment: still struggling to get this to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
/(.*)\.(.+)/
```

I think it'll works.

Comment: still splitting the url at the first period.

Comment: actually, it's splitting it at both periods now.

Comment: Use this regex as a matching function, not as a search function.

Comment: This works great, I had some other issues in my code.  Once I fixed that everything fell into line. Thanks for your help hsz

Answer (score 2):

You can match all the characters thats not a period, until it reaches the end of the line:

```
/(.*)\.([^.]+)$/
```

Comment: thanks veiset, this is also capturing any occurance of a period. I'm going to add to my original question to be a little more clear...